# How to print SQL statement in codeigniter model

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a sql statement in my model,

I then say

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array(fields, fields1);

if ($query) {
    return true:
} else {
    echo "failed";
    return false;
}
```

My query always fails, how do I get php to print the exact sql statement being sent to my database? And display that on my php view, page

Answer (score 164, accepted):

To display the query string:

```
print_r($this->db->last_query());
```

To display the query result:

```
print_r($query);
```

---

The Profiler Class will display benchmark results, queries you have run, and $_POST data at the bottom of your pages.
To enable the profiler place the following line anywhere within your Controller methods:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Profiling user guide:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html

Comment: when i do print_r($query); nothing prints out at all

Comment: Use the CI built in profiler, more info [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html)

Comment: all i want to do is print out the sql statement as passed to the database, sory but the profiler isn't helping much neither

Comment: Visit the user guide link I posted, if it is not working, tell us what happens instead.

Comment: well i figured my problem, oracle isn't accepting my date format, ive tried every format i think, it will only accept SYSDATE

Comment: This seems to output the result of the query, rather than the query itself.

Answer (score 242):

You can use this:

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

"Returns the last query that was run (the query string, not the result)."

Reff: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 42):

You can display the ActiveRecord generated SQL:

Before the query runs:

```
$this->db->_compile_select();
```

And after it has run:

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: when i use $this->db->_compile_select();  i get Fatal error: Call to protected method CI_DB_active_record::_compile_select() from

Comment: The profiler thing is no good for me, does not show the query I want, its over complicated to just get the SQL... This works for me:-
echo $this->EE->db->_compile_select();

Comment: In CI3, Use `$this->db->get_compiled_select()` instead.

Answer (score 17):

if you need a quick test on your query, this works great for me

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); die;
```

Answer (score 14):

After trying without success to use `_compiled_select()` or `get_compiled_select()` I just printed the `db` object, and you can see the query there in the `queries` property.

Try it yourself:

```
var_dump( $this->db );
```

If you know you have only one query, you can print it directly:

```
echo $this->db->queries[0];
```

Answer (score 13):

There is a new public method `get_compiled_select` that can print the query before running it. `_compile_select` is now protected therefore can not be used.

```
echo $this->db->get_compiled_select(); // before $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::get_compiled_select()

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use this at the end..

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Answer (score 4):

In CodeIgniter4, you do this:

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();  
// your queries here
$query = $db->getLastQuery();
$sql = $query->getQuery();
echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither `last_query()` or `get_compiled_select()` works for me, so a slight change of pedro's code works for me just fine. Do not include `->get()` in your build, this must be before the ->get()

```
 echo $this->EE->db->_compile_select();
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line right after the query you want to print.

Example:

**$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition');**

//Add this line.

**var_dump($this->db->last_query());**

**exit();**

or

**echo $this->db->last_query();**

Answer (score 1):

I try to @Chumillas's answer and @chhameed's answer, but it not work,because the sql is wrong.So I found new approach,**like this:**

- Insert `echo $sql; flush(); exit;` into before `return $sql;`
  `_compile_select` function of `DB_active_rec.php`

Answer (score 1):

use `get_compiled_select()` to retrieve query instead of replace it

Comment: I'd suggest to show how to use the function you propose in this particular case, not just mention it. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter 4 I use below code to echo the query.
This comes handy especially to see incorrect database queries

```
use CodeIgniter\Events\Events; 

// listen to the event before $builder->get() or $model->find()

Events::on('DBQuery', function($query){
    log_message('info', $query);
});
```

This event is triggered whenever a new query has been run, whether successful or not.

Refer official doc on DBQuery Event [here.](https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/database/events.html#dbquery)

Comment: should be declared before running `CodeIgniter\Model` query

Answer (score 0):

I read all answers here, but cannot get

```
echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
```

to work, It gave me error like,

> Call to protected method CI_DB_active_record::_compile_select() from context 'Welcome'in controllers on line xx

So i removed `protected` from the below line from file `\system\database\DB_active_rec.php` and it worked

```
protected function _compile_select($select_override = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using xdebug for watch this values in VSCode with the respective extension and CI v2.x. I add the expresion `$this->db->last_query()` in the watch section, and I add `xdebugSettings` node like these lines for get non truncate value in the launch.json.

```
{
  "name": "Launch currently open script",
  "type": "php",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${file}",
  "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
  "port": 9000,
  "xdebugSettings": {
    "max_data": -1,
    "max_children": -1
  }
},
```

And run my debuger with the breakpoint and finally just select my expresion and do click right  > copy value.

Answer (score 0):

`$query->getCompiledSelect()` worked for me.

You can check `system\Database\BaseBuilder.php`
and see which function returns sql query as string.
Found this in there and it worked for me.

```
 /**
     * Get SELECT query string
     *
     * Compiles a SELECT query string and returns the sql.
     *
     * @param boolean $reset TRUE: resets QB values; FALSE: leave QB values alone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCompiledSelect(bool $reset = true): string
    {
        $select = $this->compileSelect();
    
        if ($reset === true)
        {
            $this->resetSelect();
        }
    
        return $this->compileFinalQuery($select);
    }
```

and in `system\Database\Query.php` there is `getQuery()`. Either of this might be useful.

```
/**
     * Returns the final, processed query string after binding, etal
     * has been performed.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQuery(): string
    {
        if (empty($this->finalQueryString))
        {
            $this->finalQueryString = $this->originalQueryString;
        }

        $this->compileBinds();

        return $this->finalQueryString;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I had exactly the same problem and found the solution eventually. My query runs like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE ' . $sql_where . ' AND ' . $sql_where2 . ' ORDER BY acconame ASC ');
```

In order to display the sql command, all I had to do was to create a variable ($resultstring) with the exact same content as my query and then echo it, like this:`<?php echo $resultstring = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE ' . $sql_where . ' AND ' . $sql_where2 . ' ORDER BY acconame ASC '; ?>`

It works!

Comment: This is not the CodeIgniter way.