# Codeginiter JOIN query with DATE between and LIMIT not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get the details of a persons based on the user input age (Integer). Now my query always returns null `Array()` whenever I execute the below code. I haven't specified the `$postdata` array. You can see I have used `$postdata['ageto']` and `$postdata['agefrom']` are used in calculating `$agefrom` and `$ageto`

```
        $now = new DateTime();

    //Converting _POST age to Date
    $agefrom = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($now->format("Y")-$postdata['ageto'].'-'.$now->format("m").'-'.$now->format("d")));
    $ageto = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($now->format("Y")-$postdata['agefrom'].'-'.$now->format("m").'-'.$now->format("d")));

    $this->db->select('uacc_id, uacc_username, name, dob, city, education');
    $this->db->from('user_accounts as a');
    $this->db->join('personal as b','a.uacc_id = b.pruserid','INNER');
    $this->db->join('profession as c','a.uacc_id = c.puserid','INNER');
    $this->db->join('location as d','a.uacc_id = d.luserid','INNER');
    $this->db->where('dob >= ',$agefrom);
    $this->db->where('dob <= ',$ageto);
    $this->db->limit(10, $offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

I have suspected that my input post is not fetching the data properly. So I have replaced it with my simple query `select * from... where dob >....` and it worked well. So there is no problem with `_POST` variables. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can some one help me.

Comment: I think you can check your sql command. You can look the site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142099/how-to-print-sql-statement-in-codeigniter-model

Comment: Thanks Lighter.. I got a clue now. Its problem with the POST DATA

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to specify to which table DOB belongs like a.dob. Sorry for the post but I could not comment. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The select field should add the table name

`$this->db->select('a.uacc_id, a.uacc_username, a.name....); // example`

and your `where` add table name too.

`$this->db->where('b.dod >= ', $agefrom); // example`

or you can output the sql command.

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142099/how-to-print-sql-statement-in-codeigniter-model)

Comment: Adding the object name to column doesn't found difference