# using mssl in codeigniter, joined 2 tables and getting error with limit

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I am joining 2 tables, and its working fine.. but when i have added limit then it gives error

my model funciton is this

```
    $username = trim($this->session->userdata('userdata')['user_username']);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('sinv');
    $this->db->where('sinv.doc_type',"SI");
    $this->db->join('customer_agentREL','sinv.custcode = customer_agentREL.custcode');
    $this->db->where('customer_agentREL.agent',$username);
    $this->db->order_by("sinv.createdate DESC");
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
```

eror i am getting is

```
Error Number: 42000/8156

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The column 'custcode' was specified multiple times for 'CI_subquery'.

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY "sinv"."createdate" DESC) AS "CI_rownum", * FROM "sinv" JOIN "customer_agentREL" ON "sinv"."custcode" = "customer_agentREL"."custcode" WHERE "sinv"."doc_type" = 'SI' AND "customer_agentREL"."agent" = 'guri' ) "CI_subquery" WHERE "CI_rownum" BETWEEN 31 AND 60

Filename: C:/web/demo2.million-cloud.com/htdocs/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

can anybody help me out

Comment: try `limit($limit, $offset)` or `limit($limit)`: ex `limit(10, 200)` or `limit(10)`

Comment: or print the query and check how it perform http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142099/how-to-print-sql-statement-in-codeigniter-model