# How to select multiple where conditions using codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

my table

[image]

This is my table i have to display the data using multiple where conditions. First i select using dms_expire_date,for this i got answer and i am using dms_doc_name in where conditions but i didn't got correct result.

I have tired so far.

[image]]

See this picture if i use "or" in "where" i got testie not within this date.but if i use "and" in "where" i didn't got result for dms_expiry_date

See this picture[image]

i don't know how to do this.please help to solve this problem.

```
SELECT * FROM `dms_document` WHERE dms_expire_date BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-07-16' AND dms_doc_name = '' OR dms_category_id = '' OR dms_subcategory_id=''
```

I have tired in array also but i didn't result.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->join('dms_category as C', 'C.dms_category_id = D.dms_category_id', 'left outer');
$this->db->join('dms_sub_category as S', 'S.dms_subcategory_id = D.dms_subcategory_id', 'left outer');
$this->db->where('dms_expire_date >=', $newstart);
$this->db->where('dms_expire_date <=', $newend);
$this->db->where(array('dms_doc_name' =>$docname,'D.dms_category_id'=>$category,'D.dms_subcategory_id'=>$subcategory));
$data['documents']= $this->db->get('dms_document as D')->result_array();
```

Comment: most likely issue with brackets (),, but what result do you expect tho? what do you want to see when you have `dms_doc_name = ''`, `dms_category_id = ''` , `dms_subcategory_id = ''`

Comment: if i give testie in doc_name within given dms_expiriy date and the result should be come

Comment: tbh, I still dont get what you want

Comment: If i give expriy_date the result are coming correctly and if i give doc_name ='testie' the tesite result only come and if i give dms-category_id only that id should come and etc

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes see 2nd pic i give testie in where conditon only testie row should come extra 2 rows are displaying and if i give category_id that category_id only displayed and so far.I think you can understand

Comment: on 2nd pic, you want testie record to come out as result? note that testie record has expiry_date = 2020-04-01 which is outside of your date range?

Comment: yes but result are displaying i want 0 row

Comment: To clarify the logic you actually want, I'd recommend adding parenthesis around the conditionals like `... WHERE x AND y AND (z OR a OR b)` vs `... WHERE x AND (y AND z) OR (a OR b)` which are different queries.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * 
FROM dms_document
WHERE dms_expire_date BETWEEN $newstart AND $newend
AND CASE WHEN $docname IS NULL THEN 1 = 1 ELSE dms_doc_name = $docname END
AND CASE WHEN $category IS NULL THEN 1 = 1 ELSE dms_category_id = $category END 
AND CASE WHEN $subcategory IS NULL THEN 1 = 1 ELSE dms_subcategory_id = $subcategory END
```

--

edited. waiting for clearance.

if I get what you mean correctly, it is problem with understanding AND, OR, and the priority with brackets ()

--
if anyone want to use the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd96ce2726eb215d4ec1151a387201ea), I have created the sample data for this issue

Comment: i give one example pic

Comment: see the excel image that last column is result but it is dms_doc_tag

Comment: last column? that column with 1,1,2,0,2,1,2,1 values? what do those values suppose to mean regarding the result you expected

Comment: let's wait for other helper, maybe they can understand your point better than I do.

Comment: you didn;t understad okay where i your answer

Comment: i got error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NULL THEN 1 = 1 ELSE dms_doc_name = END AND CASE WHEN IS NULL THEN 1 = 1 E' at line 4

Comment: by $newstart, $newend, $docname, $category, $subcategory. replace them with your variables/parameters values

Comment: i have tired in application not in phpadmin

Answer (score 0):

You can write `OR` using CodeIgniter's `or_where()` ([v3 docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)) or `orWhere()` ([v4 docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#id3)).

```
//your initial query
$sql = "SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `dms_document`
        WHERE
            dms_expire_date BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-07-16'
            AND dms_doc_name = ''
            OR dms_category_id = ''
            OR dms_subcategory_id=''";

//building the same query using CI
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('dms_document');
$this->db->where('dms_expire_date >=', '2020-05-01');
$this->db->where('dms_expire_date <=', '2020-07-16');
$this->db->where('dms_doc_name', '');
$this->db->or_where('dms_category_id', '');
$this->db->or_where('dms_subcategory_id', '');
```

You can confirm the query this generates by running `$this->db->_compile_select();` or `$this->db->last_query();` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6145021/1499877 for reference).

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($sql);
var_dump($this->db->_compile_select());
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

Comment: i tired this before itself but i didn't get correct result

Comment: I've updated this answer to match the query you initially posted. Can you please clarify if you are trying to replicate that exact query or if you're trying to do something else? I'm not sure where your JOINs came from in CI because your initial query doesn't have them.